# Node.js + Express + Handlebars.js + partial views

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, partial-views

I am trying to make a simple HelloWorld project with Node.js|Express using Handlebars.js as a server template engine.

The problem is that I couldn't find any examples of using such chain, especially with multiple view.

For example I would like to define header view:

```
<header>
  <span>Hello: {{username}}</span>
</header>
```

And use it in every page with other views.

Maybe I am thinking about this views in a wrong way, I thought that view is kind of control that I can reuse on any page inside any other view.

I appreciate any link to the tutorial or (much better) open source project that I can lear from.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I know this had been asked a long time ago, but no one has shown an answer in this post. So I will do so here. To ensure everyone is on the same page, I will be verbose in my answer. I apologize in advance if it seems overly simplistic.

In your server.js file (or app.js, wherever you defined handlebars as your view engine). Depending on what you are using as your npm package, such as hbs or express-handlebars etc. it may look different, but similar to this. Note: I'm using express-handlebars in this example.

*file: server.js*

```
...
var express     = require( 'express'),
    hbs         = require( 'express-handlebars' ),
    app         = express();
...

app.engine( 'hbs', hbs( { 
  extname: 'hbs', 
  defaultLayout: 'main', 
  layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/',
  partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials/'
} ) );

app.set( 'view engine', 'hbs' );

...
```

and your file structure should look something like this:

```
| /views/   
|--- /layouts/
|----- main.hbs
|--- /partials/
|----- header.hbs
|----- footer.hbs
|----- ... etc.
|--- index.hbs
| server.js
```

And your main.hbs file should look like this:

*file: main.hbs*

```
...
{{> header }}
...
<span> various other stuff </span>
...
{{> footer }}
```

To denote a partial you use this syntax: `{{> partialsNames }}`.

Comment: This is so helpful. Now, when I go to render a view, which includes multiple partials, how do I send it? suppose I have `var router=express.Router()` and `router.get("/", function(req, res){ ...some data function... res.render('index', {some: data}, [partials])`. What gets passed as the option here? How do I tell `render()` to post data to the proper partial?

Comment: I had the same question, and this provided the context around this good answer: https://hackersandslackers.com/handlebars-templates-expressjs/

Answer (score 39):

Using https://www.npmjs.org/package/hbs | https://github.com/donpark/hbs

Let's assume you have:

```
+ views
  - index.hbs
  + partials
    - footer.hbs
```

You need to register which folder contains your partials:

```
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');
```

The partials will have the exact name that the file has. You can also register specific names for your partials by using:

```
hbs.registerPartial('myFooter', fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/views/partials/footer.hbs', 'utf8'));
```

Then you access it like this:

```
First example: {{> footer }} 
Second example: {{> myFooter }}
```

Full example here: https://github.com/donpark/hbs/tree/master/examples/partial

Comment: can you make a full example with code? The documentation is scarce

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently using ericf's implementation of "handlebars-express", and find it to be excellent:

https://github.com/ericf/express3-handlebars

The key thing to remember is that on express, as opposed to the within the browser, handlebars gets activated during the view render phase. The client code will end up being just plain HTML, as if you'd used mustache within a PHP context.

Comment: this doesnt really answer the question... whats recommended code structure to achieve OP's scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use partials.

See https://github.com/donpark/hbs/tree/master/examples/partial for a good example of using partials.

Here's another example http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers

Answer (score 0):

If your current directory is something like this then,

```
| /public/   
| /views/ 
|--- /layouts/
|----- main.hbs 
|--- /partials/ 
|----- header.hbs 
|----- footer.hbs 
|----- sidebar.hbs 
|--- index.hbs 
| app.js
```

Then the structure of app.js will be

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3001;
const path = require('path');
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); 

app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
app.engine('.hbs', handlebars({
    layoutsDir: __dirname + '/public/views/layouts',
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: 'hbs', 
    //for partial directory
    partialsDir : __dirname+'/public/views/partials',
}));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/public/views'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {  
    res.render('index');
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening to port ${port}`));
```

Set the main.hbs as follows

```
const express = require('express');
{{> header}}
{{> sidebar}}
<p>Your Content(static) or you can use {{{body}}} </p>
{{> footer}}
```