# Using nodejs and handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

Hi everybody I'm kind new in nodejs problems I hope o can found what I need as simple as possible
So my base problem is how can I use multiple handlebars files in one handlebar page as sections
Like to have a page for the headear and another for the body and others for footer and all that just by using nodejs and handlebars ... And thanks after all ^^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js + Express + Handlebars.js + partial views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385173/node-js-express-handlebars-js-partial-views)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the pages except main page as partials. Then you the files in your main file in the form of **{{> filename}}**

for eg:

```
views/
    main.handelbars
    partials/
        -header.handelbars
        -body.handelbars
        -footer.handelbars
```

**main.handlebars**

```
<html>
<title>xxxxxx</title>
<head>
.....
</head>
{{> header}}
{{> body}}
{{> footer}}
</html>
```

**header.handlebars**

```
<header>
........
</header>
```

**body.handlebars**

```
<div>
........
</div>
```

**footer.handlebars**

```
<footer>
........
</footer>
```

Dont't forget to add the view engine and mention the public directory to **views** as well as the **partials** directory.

Comment: Thanks to much for your answer I just would  like to get more informations about je side ^^