# how can I include file through node.js to .handlebar file

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

Can I add another file to a .hbs file?
for example, to "*index.hbs*" I want to add "*footer.hbs*".
Something like php "include *footer.php*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Take a look at Handlebars [partials](https://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html)

A pretty detailed answer and tutorial can be found here on this topic:
[Node.js + Express + Handlebars.js + partial views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385173/node-js-express-handlebars-js-partial-views)